# undefined offset error in php somewhere in the date and time error

Tags: javascript, php, sql

I am making a program for updating the database and by the time I clicked the update button it displays an error like this:

```
Notice: Undefined offset: 2 in C:\xampp\htdocs\maritime_database\students_entry.php on line 103

Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in C:\xampp\htdocs\maritime_database\students_entry.php on line 103
```

it is somewhere in the line 103 and this is the code:

```
<?php

if($opr=="upd")
{
    $sql_upd=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM students WHERE stud_id=$id");
    $rs_upd=mysql_fetch_array($sql_upd);
    list($y,$m,$d)=explode('-',$rs_upd['dob']);
?>
```

Comment: print_r($rs_upd); To see the output

Comment: Array ( [0] => 1300018 [stud_id] => 1300018 [1] => Mark [fname] => Mark [2] => Orlando [lname] => Orlando [3] => Male [gender] => Male [4] => 1992-02-19 [dob] => 1992-02-19 [5] => Ozamiz City [pob] => Ozamiz City [6] => Muslim [religion] => Muslim [7] => Marawi, Zamboanga [address] => Marawi, Zamboanga [8] => 09268010101 [phone] => 09268010101 [9] => m@gmail.com [email] => m@gmail.com [10] => student [note] => student )

Comment: "list($y,$m,$d)=explode('-',$rs_upd['dob']);" this one causes an error

Comment: Why do you want to explode the date?

Answer (score 0):

Why you parse date manually ? PHP has date built-in function :

```
<?php
 if($opr=="upd"){
    $sql_upd = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM students WHERE stud_id=$id");
    $rs_upd = mysql_fetch_array($sql_upd);
    $dob = strtotime($rs_upd['dob']); // Convert into UNIX time
    $y = date("Y",$dob); // Extract Year
    $m = date("m",$dob); // Extract Month
    $d = date("d",$dob); // Extract Day
    echo "Day : ".$d."\n";
    echo "Month : ".$m."\n";
    echo "Year : ".$y."\n";
 }
?>
```